# ubuntu stalls during installation on acer powerseries

Tags: installation

During completeerase and install of boot drive, the process seems to be hanging endlessly. The progress bar has notmoved for awhile, and it has been stuck on "retrieving file 53 of 85" for some time. The hardrive light is off, but it hasn't flickered at all. Not even when it was progressing through files. Is any of this normal?

Edit: retried. Must have been a network issue.

Comment: Did it work upon retrying?

Answer (score 1):

Stated by OP

Retried. Must have been a network issue

Answer (score 0):

Click on the arrow that expands the terminal and click the Skip button. This will unfreeze the install. If it does not and the computer appears to have locked up, try installing without an internet conection. Is this a wubi or dual boot or a full install (formatting hard drive and devoting all of it to Ubuntu)?